# Overloading static method with generics

Tags: typescript

I encapsulated an instance builder in the class as static method and created an inherited class.

```
type Maybe<T> = T | undefined;

interface A {
    a: number
}

interface B extends A {
    b: number
}

class X<T extends A> {
    constructor(
        public property: T
    ) {}

    static tryCreate<T_in_X extends A>(p: T_in_X): Maybe<X<T_in_X>> {
        if (p.a === 123) { // Some check just as example.
            return new this(p);
        }
    }
}

class Y<T extends B> extends X<T> {
    static tryCreate<T_in_Y extends B>(p: T_in_Y): Maybe<Y<T_in_Y>> {
        if (p.a === 456 && p.b === 789) { // Some check just as example.
            return new this(p);
        }
    }
}
```

[Code in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Maybe<T>%20%3D%20T%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20X<T%20extends%20A>%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20property%3A%20T%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20tryCreate<T_in_X%20extends%20A>(p%3A%20T_in_X)%3A%20Maybe<X<T_in_X>>%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(p.a%20%3D%3D%3D%20123)%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20Some%20check%20just%20as%20example.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20this(p)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Y<T%20extends%20B>%20extends%20X<T>%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20tryCreate<T_in_Y%20extends%20B>(p%3A%20T_in_Y)%3A%20Maybe<Y<T_in_Y>>%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(p.a%20%3D%3D%3D%20456%20%26%26%20p.b%20%3D%3D%3D%20789)%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20Some%20check%20just%20as%20example.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20this(p)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

I expected that `Y.tryCreate` extends `X.tryCreate` but get compile-time error:

```
Class static side 'typeof Y' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof X'.
  Types of property 'tryCreate' are incompatible.
    Type '<T_in_Y extends B>(p: T_in_Y) => Y<T_in_Y>' is not assignable to type '<T_in_X extends A>(p: T_in_X) => X<T_in_X>'.
      Types of parameters 'p' and 'p' are incompatible.
        Type 'T_in_X' is not assignable to type 'B'.
          Property 'b' is missing in type 'A' but required in type 'B'.
```

`T_in_Y` should to be extension of `T_in_X`

Why it checks that a parameter of a base class static method should to be assignable to type of a child class method parameter and not vice versa?

Comment: Probably similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521800/how-do-i-overload-generic-methods-to-make-them-less-generic-in-typescript

Comment: @MebinJoe, thanks. That's what I need!

Comment: No way to completely solve it because static methods is not polymorphic. More details: [Polymorphic "this" for static members · Issue #5863 · Microsoft/TypeScript · GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863)